# Can I declare and call functions in javascript like in php

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can this be done? I'm coming form php and trying to optimize jquery code I'm writing for validation and I'm repeating my self a lot.

This would be the function:

```
function errorHint(e,hint){

        if(e.parent().hasClass("has-success")){
            return false;
        }else{
            e.addClass('form-control');
            e.parent().addClass('has-error');
            e.parent().append('<span id="glyph-error" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>');
            e.parent().append('<div class="error-hint-empty alert alert alert-warning"><span class="warning-glyph glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>'+hint+'</div>');
            if(e.parent().hasClass("has-success")){
                            e.parent().removeClass("has-success");
                            e.parent().find('span#glyph-ok').remove();
            }
        }

    }
```

And I would call it like this:

```
if($('#username').length){
    if(testuser == 0 && $('#username').val() !=='' && $('#username').val() !== null){
        hint = 'That user already exists!';
        errorHint($("#username"),hint);
        formvalid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do but you shouldn't override the default `alert` function.

Comment: `function alert (text){
    alert(text);
}` Is obsolete. Alert is standard javascript code..

Comment: @JonKoops this is only simple example. I'm checking multiple forms and fields adding css and appending elements. Some of those actions are repetitive for different elements in DOM on different events. So i would like to store adding css and appending elements in function and call that function on event and pass it parameter which would be element id.

Comment: What is being asked here? "Can I write functions in javascript like php"...uh...wut? What problem are you trying to solve. Show us where you are repeating yourself and maybe people can suggest better ways.

Comment: @user3275701 I think you should update your question, it's very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be:

```
function Alert (text){
    alert(text);
}

$(form).on("submit", function() {
    var text = 'This is alert text';        
    Alert(text);
});
```

This is because there is an ambiguous call between javascript's native `alert` and your defined `alert`. So I changed the function name to `Alert`, which should work fine.

## Just a side thought..

Why are you doing this?

You can just use `alert(text)`.

I don't think what you are doing is called code optimization. It is called code lengthification ;)

My advice is if you aren't doing anything inside `Alert()` except again just alerting, you should be better off using native `alert('some text');`

Comment: Amit this was just simple example, I replied on Jon comment what I'm trying to do. Please share your thought...

Comment: Would't recommend beginning of a function name with a capital letter, since it's a common practice to indicate a constructor function with that.

Comment: I've updated post with my example so please take a lok

Comment: Thx Amit, I should be more concise at the start

Comment: @user3275701, you should change your question to the original, other wise people will down vote me thinking that I have answered wrongly ;)